# Is possible parsing xml file that contains only one node by using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

As a beginner, I have read about `NSXMLParser` and try to implement a parser for parsing an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>Some text here</a>
```

my implementation

```
-(OneNodeXMLParser*)initOneNodeXMLParser{

appDelegate = (OneNodeXMLParser*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,nil);
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"]){
   // init some varibles
}
NSLog(@"Starting processing");
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,nil);
NSLog(@"%s",string);
}

   -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,nil);
NSLog(@"Finishing processing");
}
```

What should I modify to parse the file successfully?

Comment: you can parse xml with single node.

Comment: Could you explain more detail, where I should modify in the above code, I wanna get that text to use later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.h` file declare a `NSMutableString *store;`

And change the following methods like:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"])
  {
     store = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
  NSLog(@"Starting processing");
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  NSLog(@"%s",string);
   if (store != nil)
   {
     [store appendString:string];
   }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 {
   NSLog(@"Finishing processing String : %@", store);
 }
```

You can use that string variable `store` for future use.